# Laravel asset() helper function is not loading on long URL routes (example.com/admin/dashboard/main)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 10.0^ and I have a problem with the `asset()` helper function. I want to load some CSS and JS files from the public folder in my blade template. I am using the `asset()` helper function like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

This works fine when I visit the URL `example.com/admin`, but when I visit a longer route URL like `example.com/admin/dashboard/main`, the `asset()` helper function does not work. It tries to load the files from the wrong path, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="admin/css/style.css">
<script src="admin/js/script.js"></script>
```

This causes a 404 error and the CSS and JS files are not loaded. I have tried to clear the cache, run php artisan optimize, and use `url()` instead of `asset()`, but none of them solved the problem.

How can I fix this issue? Why is the `asset()` helper function not working on longer route URL? Is there any configuration or setting that I need to change?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you.

I want to load my public folder assets correctly.

Comment: your file is located in public folder in this path admin/css/style.css ?

Comment: can you tell the file path which you want to access using asset()

Comment: if this "admin/css/style.css"  is right path in public folder then this should b access using this asset('admin/css/style.css')

Comment: @UmerFayyaz, not I am addressing it correctly according to Laravel filling documentation, but when page rendered the file URL followed by the second step URL.